# Kotlin Fragment Recyclerview not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Whenever a new message is sent, I want the recycler view to update. the log shows the uid's in the right order, but the view does not reflect that. I did see somewhere mention of moving a single item. I've tried that but couldn't get it to work right. Moving the single item is definitely preferred. I moved the `recycler_view_chatlist.adapter = userAdapter` bit around to see if that would work, but to no avail. I also had `userAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()` and it had the same outcome. I tried creating a function in my UserAdapter and calling it from my fragment. I'm at a loss...

edit* I added some code to the fragment.

Here is a bit of my ChatsFragment:

```
//edit
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private fun addMsg() {
            if (sortedMsg?.size!! >= 2) {
                sortedMsg?.union(sortedMsg!!)
            }
                sortMsg(sortedMsg)
                getUid()
                Log.d("ARRAY AFTER SORT", sortMsg(sortedMsg).toString())
        }    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun sortMsg(sortedMsg: List<String>?): List<String>? {
        Log.d("LAST ID", lastId)
            val dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime: (String) -> LocalDateTime = {
                LocalDateTime.parse(
                    it.substring(0, 26),
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSSSSS")
                )
            }
            val finalSort = sortedMsg?.sortedByDescending(dateTimeStrToLocalDateTime)
            return finalSort
    }
//end edit
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private fun getUid() {
            val userArray = ArrayList<String>()
            val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        for (item in sortMsg(sortedMsg)!!) {
                            val stringVal = p0.child(item).getValue(Chat::class.java)
                            Log.d("SET UID item", item)
                            if (stringVal != null) {
                                if (stringVal.getReceiver() != firebaseUser!!.uid) {
                                    userArray.add(stringVal.getReceiver()!!)
                                }
                                if (stringVal.getSender() != firebaseUser.uid) {
                                    userArray.add(stringVal.getSender()!!)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("USER ARRAY", userArray.toString())
                        setUid(userArray)
                }
    
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
        }
    
        private fun setUid(userArray: ArrayList<String>) {
            val latestMsgId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
            latestMsgId.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                    if (!executed) {
    
                        val user = p0.child(firebaseUser!!.uid).getValue(Users::class.java)
                        latestMsgId.child(firebaseUser!!.uid).child("lastMsg").setValue(userArray)
                        val sortedUsers = user?.getLastMsg()
    
                        Log.d("SORTED USERS", sortedUsers.toString())
    
                        for (item in sortedUsers!!) {
    
                            val uidVal = p0.child(item).getValue(Users::class.java)
                            uidArray.add(uidVal!!)
                            Log.d("UID VAL", uidVal.getUserName().toString())
                            executed = true
                        }
                    }
                    userAdapter = UserAdapter(p0, context!!, uidArray, true)
                    recycler_view_chatlist.adapter = userAdapter
                }
    
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                }
            })
        }
```

Here's the UserAdapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
        R.layout.user_search_item_layout,
        viewGroup,
        false
    )
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    val user: Users = mUsers[i]
    val userVisitId: String? = user.getUID()
    val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    //use data from mUsers...
```

Here's the Logcat:

```
2020-10-19 19:22:08.632 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 2020-10-19 02:51:50:192000-MJylHpCC_Lf5aKy70vv found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat
2020-10-19 19:22:08.633 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 2020-10-19 03:37:43:137000-MJyvmw6URelqbe6Po-O found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat
2020-10-19 19:22:08.633 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 2020-10-19 03:32:45:371000-MJyueEPOCBKEV_gVI6z found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat
2020-10-19 19:22:08.633 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 2020-10-19 22:46:25:902000-MK21hTuH3sRADWn9HQz found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat
2020-10-19 19:22:08.633 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for 2020-10-19 02:29:00:370000-MJyg3OZIxJtBRq1ZrKM found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat
2020-10-19 19:22:08.633 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY BEFORE SORT: [2020-10-19 23:18:58:435000-MK299AVpBCKcPx_NdR0, 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn]
2020-10-19 19:22:08.640 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/LAST ID: 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn
2020-10-19 19:22:08.658 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/LAST ID: 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn
2020-10-19 19:22:08.658 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/ARRAY AFTER SORT: [2020-10-19 23:18:58:435000-MK299AVpBCKcPx_NdR0, 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn]
2020-10-19 19:22:08.660 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-19 23:18:58:435000-MK299AVpBCKcPx_NdR0
2020-10-19 19:22:08.660 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn
2020-10-19 19:22:08.660 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/USER ARRAY: [5l5iy4Tg0zfp7DyqMtvBphEsmnh1, KQ78XVs7ezRRcduEU6gUHUrCj7i1]
2020-10-19 19:22:08.662 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-19 23:18:58:435000-MK299AVpBCKcPx_NdR0
2020-10-19 19:22:08.663 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/SET UID item: 2020-10-19 23:18:50:285000-MK297B92yt4GeyYe8hn
2020-10-19 19:22:08.663 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/USER ARRAY: [5l5iy4Tg0zfp7DyqMtvBphEsmnh1, KQ78XVs7ezRRcduEU6gUHUrCj7i1]
2020-10-19 19:22:08.664 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/SORTED USERS: [5l5iy4Tg0zfp7DyqMtvBphEsmnh1, KQ78XVs7ezRRcduEU6gUHUrCj7i1]
2020-10-19 19:22:08.664 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Jerry
2020-10-19 19:22:08.664 11190-11190/com.score.scorev2 D/UID VAL: Ethan
```

What is shown in the app
[image: What is shown in the app]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an updateData function in the adapter class and call it where you are printing values. There is no need to assigning adapter again and again.

Shift your adapter code below first line of method as below -

```
val latestMsgId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
userAdapter = UserAdapter(p0, context!!, uidArray, true)
recycler_view_chatlist.adapter = userAdapter
```

Add below method to your adapter class -

```
  public fun updateData(list:ArrayList<Users>) {
    this.mUsers= list
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
```

Call this method as below -

```
val uidVal = p0.child(item).getValue(Users::class.java)
uidArray.add(uidVal!!)
Log.d("UID VAL", uidVal.getUserName().toString())
executed = true
userAdapter.updateData(uidArray)
```

Comment: Okay, so I made those changes and it still isn't updating. However, it will update once I leave the activity and return to it.

Comment: For instant changes you need to integrate different things. First you need to check if your listener is called every time when you are changing data from backend or not.

Comment: I don't think it's being called, and I'm getting this message `2020-10-22 14:17:59.106 14167-14167/com.score.scorev2 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for (message id here) found on class com.score.scorev2.ModelClasses.Chat` for every single message. Not sure if that is a part of my current problem or not. What do you think I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, It needs refresh to update your view. Otherwise you will not be able to see the changes, You need to come back to screen to see the changes.

Comment: Okay, I've looked up how to refresh the data from a few places. It seems getUid is not being called somehow on the refresh, and that may be why it's not updating. What are your thoughts? Thanks. I'll add more of my fragment.

Comment: Yes, Please accept answer if it worked for you. Thanks